# Add email page link button to a webpage

Tags: email, button, social-media

I'm adding social media buttons to my website. Facebook like, Twitter tweet etc buttons were very easy.

However I also need an email the page (or rather a link to the page) button. I have trawled the internet but cannot find a simple and good implementation.

Ideally I'd like to be able to copy some reliable code, and have the button look in the same style as the ones on this page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6920023/testbuttons.html

If anyone has done this before I would be very glad to hear from you :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you will have to use `Mailto:` apart from doing some deep Gmail, Yahoo and Hotmail API integration. That's about as good as your going to get.

You can dynamically fill out subject, body, cc fields etc using javascript/php (or whatever you are using)

Comment: Thanks, looks like that was the simplest way. Am now just using a basic mailto: link.

Comment: Probably best to mention that if the user does not have a default email client installed this won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the AddThis service? You simply register, provide them with your website url and then select the social media / link mechanisms you would like to use on your site. At the end they provide you with a block of HTML code to drop into your site and low and behold, the buttons and appearance you selected will be present. You can also select mechanism such as pain old email when setting it up.

An example of it in place;
[image]

Here's the link: http://www.addthis.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's a nice service, but it would have the AddThis link at the bottom, which isn't okay for this usage unfortunately.

Comment: @Jonathan, you can add a tiny bit of javascript to remove the unwanted links / sections of the tool. AddThis actually endorse this; see here: http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21888